# Image beside a paragraph bootstrap 2.3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello so I have a simple html code:

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" src="image.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
   The long text that isn't continuing at the bottom of the image is here...
  </div>
</div>
```

And the output is:
[image]

Now my problem is that the text is not continuing below the image and btw I am using bootstrap 2.3.1 because that's the version of the template I bought. How can I move the other text below the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `media-body`:

```
<div class="media">    
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">    
    <img class="media-object" src="image.jpg">
  </a>
  <div>
   The long text that isn't continuing at the bottom of the image is here...
  </div>
</div>
```

See this working: http://www.bootply.com/d7HJMUoipg

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.